# What is the point of calling super in custom error classes in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, pylint

So I have a simple custom error class in Python that I created based on the Python 2.7 documentation:

```
class InvalidTeamError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message='This user belongs to a different team'):
        self.message = message
```

This gives me warning `W0231: __init__ method from base class %r is not called` in PyLint so I go look it up and am given the very helpful description of "explanation needed." I'd normally just ignore this error but I have noticed that a ton code online includes a call to super in the beginning of the **init** method of custom error classes so my question is: Does doing this actually serve a purpose or is it just people trying to appease a bogus pylint warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was a valid pylint warning: by not using the superclass `__init__` you can miss out on implementation changes in the parent class.  And, indeed, you have - because `BaseException.message` has been deprecated as of Python 2.6.

Here would be an implementation which will avoid your warning W0231 and will also avoid python's deprecation warning about the `message` attribute.

```
class InvalidTeamError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message='This user belongs to a different team'):
        super(InvalidTeamError, self).__init__(message)
```

This is a better way to do it, because the [implementation for `BaseException.__str__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6f6e56bb10aa/Objects/exceptions.c#l100) only considers the 'args' tuple, it doesn't look at message at all.  With your old implementation, `print InvalidTeamError()` would have only printed an empty string, which is probably not what you wanted!

Comment: Huge thumbs-up for linking to the C implementation. Makes it immediately clear, whats going on!

Comment: Annoying that [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) actually suggest using the `self.message` approach and not calling `super()` approach.

Comment: @kevlarr Hmm, yep, that part of the docs is over 10 years old and likely predated the deprecation of `BaseException.message`.

Comment: Definitely - it's a little misleading that the docs _for 3.8_ aren't really kept up to date, but I understand why they aren't... Surface area is astonishingly large.

Answer (score -1):

Lookinv at the cpython2.7 source code there should be no problem avoiding that call to super **init** and Yes it's done just because its generally a good practice to call base class init in your init.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c see line 60 for BaseException init and line 456 how Exception derives from BaseException.